# React loops and setting state

Tags: reactjs, loops, state

I am trying to set a state for each item in a loop. As of now I am creating a data object based on the component's props. I am adding a `copied` value to the state. Here is example code to show:

```
const Example Page = ({
   tests = [], ...
}: Props) => {
    ...

  const copied = tests;
  copied.map((test) => {
    const data = {
      test: test.name,
      copied: false,
    };
    return { data };
  });

  const [copySuccess, setCopyStatus] = React.useState<TestsCopied>(copied);

  ....
 );
};
```

I have a feeling how I have this setup is incorrect. I want to be able to set a state for each item in the loop, but I'm not sure the best way to handle that.

Here is how this loop is implemented:

```
return (
  ...

    <TestWrapper>
        {
            tests.map((test, index) => {
                let copyText = 'Copy code';

                const status = copySuccess[index];

                if (promoStatus && promoStatus.copied) {
                    copyText = 'Copied!';
                }

                return (
                    <Test key={index}>
                        <TestCopyBtn onClick={() => copyToClipboard(test.name, index)} textColor={copyColor}>
                            {copyText}
                        </TestCopyBtn>
                    </Promo>
                );
            })
        }
    </TestWrapper>

    ...
)
```

And here is the function in which I am handling the state:

```
const copyToClipboard = (copyID, index) => {
  const copyText = document.getElementById(copyID);

  if (copyText) {
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    setCopyStatus((prevState) => {
      const data = prevState[index];
      data.copied = true;

      return { ...prevState, data };
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`copied.map` would return a new array. Also rather than returning `{ data }`, I think you want to return `data` if your intention is to access `copyStatus[0].copied`. Returning `{ data }` means you'll have to access like `copyStatus[0].data.copied`. Hope that helps. Here's the code:

```js
const copied = tests.map((test) => {
  const data = {
    test: test.name,
    copied: false,
  };
  return data;
});
```

The following terse version should work too. Although if that is not readable, I would advise against that:

```js
const [copySuccess, setCopyStatus] = React.useState<TestsCopied>(tests.map(test => {
  return {
    test: test.name,
    copied: false,
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @ron4ex this is great!